# Python: Find the Max Number Can Get As Sum of Multi-Set?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

**Question:**
Given a multiset of integers, find the max number we can get as the sum of a sub-multiset of these integers such that no 2 integers have an absolute difference of 1

**For example:**

> 1. If the multiset is `[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,15]`,
>     the max sum is (1+1+3+3+3+5+5+5 = 26)
> 2. If the multiset is `[3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,10,20]`,
>     the max sum is (3+3+5+5+5+5+10+20 = 56)

**My attempt:**

This is similar to another question relating to finding the subset with maximum sum such that no two elements are adjacent to each other. For that particular question, I used a dynamic programming approach and used that same approach to try to solve this question, but haven't been successful. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
  from collections import Counter
  def max_sum(nums):
    c = Counter(nums)
    N = sorted(set(nums))
    if len(N) == 0:
      return 0
    if len(N) == 1:
      return c[N[0]]*N[0]
    if len(N) == 2:
      return max(c[N[0]]*N[0], c[N[1]]*N[1])

    dp = [0] * len(N)
    dp[0] = c[N[0]]*N[0]

    if (N[1] - N[0]) == 1:
      dp[1] = max(c[N[0]]*N[0], c[N[1]]*N[1])
    else:
      dp[1] = sum([c[N[0]]*N[0], c[N[1]]*N[1]])

    for i in range(2, len(N)):
      if (N[i] - N[i-1]) == 1:
        dp[i] = max(c[N[i]]*N[i] + dp[i-2], dp[i-1])
      else: 
        dp[i] = dp[i-1] + c[N[i]]*N[i]
      
    return dp[-1]
  
  max_sum([1,1,1,5,5,5,6,6,6])
```